# QTreeWidget can I keep selection after clear()

Tags: qt

I'm currently rebuilding my QTreeWidget every time it updates. The problem with this is my selection gets thrown away. Is there a work around for this or is it just best to find a way to update the values instead of rebuilding the tree? I would like to keep the selection from the previous time the method was called.

**This method is called every second.**

```
 void insertIntoTree(QTreeWidget *tree) {
        tree->clear();
        tree->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::SingleSelection)
        for (int i = 0; i < tree.members(); i++) {
        tree->addTopLevelItem(parent);
        parent->addChild(variousData); // Re-adds all the items into the tree, this is done every iteration
   } 
//Here I would like to save something that tells which Item in the widget is selected.
}
```

**ui code for widget**

```
  <widget class="QTreeWidget" name="treeWidget">
          <property name="focusPolicy">
           <enum>Qt::ClickFocus</enum>
          </property>
          <property name="styleSheet">
           <string notr="true">QTreeView::branch:has-siblings:!adjoins-item {
    border-image: url(:/img/res/stylesheet-vline.png) 0;
}

QTreeView::branch:has-siblings:adjoins-item {
    border-image: url(:/img/res/stylesheet-branch-more.png) 0;
}

QTreeView::branch:!has-children:!has-siblings:adjoins-item {
    border-image: url(:/img/res/stylesheet-branch-end.png) 0;
}

QTreeView::branch:has-children:!has-siblings:closed,
QTreeView::branch:closed:has-children:has-siblings {
        border-image: none;
        image: url(:/img/res/stylesheet-branch-closed.png);
}

QTreeView::branch:open:has-children:!has-siblings,
QTreeView::branch:open:has-children:has-siblings  {
        border-image: none;
        image: url(:/img/res/stylesheet-branch-open.png);
}</string>
```

Comment: Usually its faster to update the items than to erase everything and re-add it later. 1 Thought: Use a QTreeView (Model-Based) and write a proper Model. Than when you add data to your model the view will update automatically

Comment: @Marko Marinkovic: I agree. You really have to learn how to use the MCV Classes in Qt. It took some while to fully grasp it, but afterwards you will gain much more speed in developing high quality applications. As a model you can often resort to `QStandardItemModel`, which fits for almost all usages.

Comment: Thanks for your input guys I will look into this.